# How to declare a function type as a parameter in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, syntax

I have a setState function in React that I would like to pass in to another function as a parameter. I was wondering how I can define this in TypeScript without using the "any" as the type:

So far it looks like this:

```
export const keyDownHandler = (
  event: React.KeyboardEvent,
  buttonDate: number,
  setShowCalendar: any
): void => {
  // stuff happening
  setShowCalendar(false);
};
```

Comment: Try `Function`?

Comment: `type ShowCalendar= (boolen) => void
export const keyDownHandler = (event: React.KeyboardEvent, buttonDate: number, setShowCalendar: ShowCalendar): void => {
// stuff happening
setShowCalendar(false)
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of a React state setter from `useState` is `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<stateType>>`. In your case, it looks like the state type is `boolean`, so:

```typescript
export const keyDownHandler = (event: React.KeyboardEvent, buttonDate: number, setShowCalendar: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>): void => {
    // stuff happening
    setShowCalendar(false);
};
```

You can see this in `index.d.ts` in `@types/react`, or in a decent IDE (VSCode for instance), you can see it by hovering your mouse over the state setter:

[image: Cursor over state setter showing popup with const setShowCalendar: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>]

In VSCode, hovering over `setShowCalendar` shows this popup:

> `const setShowCalendar: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the type definition like this.

```
setShowCalendar: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be `(b: boolean) => void`, but if you want the full type, you can use `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function type for this. For example, a function that takes a boolean and returns nothing would be something like:

```
const setShowCalendar = (value: boolean) => {
   ... 
   logic
   ...
}
```

setShowCalendar's type would be `let setShowCalendar: (value: boolean) => void;` The type looks almost like the function itself, except for the fact that the body is missing.

Look up the types you're consuming and replace it in the above example Type Declaration.

You can read more about this here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#function-types

Comment: React state setters aren't that simple.